# Laravel - Stop concurrent access to record

Tags: php, laravel, concurrency, laravel-session

In Laravel is there any way to stop interacting with the same record simultaneously. For example, if User A is editing a record then at the same time I need to stop User B from editing same record.

**Note: I am using SESSION_DRIVER=file & Laravel 5.2**

There are around 500+ users using the system currently and it is kind of Admin panel where admins interact with the records but I need to stop concurrent access.  what would be the optimum solution.

Comment: How is this record placed in database ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I am able to achieve this.

1) Create a migration to add 2 columns in the model `is_editing` and `editing_by` and `updated_at` 
   (no need to created `updated_at` if already there)

2) Make middleware `php artisan make:middleware StopConcurrentOperations`.

3) Register the middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` under `$routeMiddleware`.

4) Apply middleware to the controller

```html
$this->middleware('concurrent.operations',["only"=>["edit","update"]]);
```

5) Block concurrent edits in middleware

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\OperationActivity;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class StopConcurrentOperations
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $operation_id = current($request->route()->parameters());
        $user_id = Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id;
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->user() && !empty($operation_id)){
            $activity = OperationActivity::firstOrNew(["operation_id" => $operation_id]);
            if($activity->is_editing && $activity->updated_at->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now())<5 && $activity->editing_by!=$user_id)
                abort(409);
            else {
                $activity->is_editing = true;
                $activity->editing_by = $user_id;
                $activity->save();
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

here I am checking if someone already editing the record and checking the time when was editing performed.

6) Optionally on the client side if the editing user closes the windows then to unblock the record like

```html
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var url = "{{route('unlock_route_name',$operation->id)}}";
    $.ajax({ url: url, method: 'post' })
  };
```

to complete the process from the client side you have to create a **route** and a **method** in the controller and just unlock the record like

```html
      $operation = Operation::findOrFail($id);
      $activity = $operation->activities()->where("is_editing",true)->first();
      $activity->is_editing = false;
      $activity->save();
```

**Note: In my example, I have different table to log activites alerady `OperationActivity` and likely Model name is `Operation`**

Answer (score 4):

I recently implemented something similar.

For each concerned table add a column named "lock" of type "dateTime" like follows:

```
 $table->dateTime('lock')->nullable();
```

Now go to the controller and find the "edit" method. In here you have to check if 'lock' is set. If it is, you have to check if it is older than, say, 15 minutes (this is important because, if a user quits the page without updating the record, it will be locked forever). This can be coded like this:

```
$sample = $this->sampleRepository->getById($idsample);
if (!$sample->lock || (strtotime($sample->lock) < strtotime('-15minutes'))) {
    // Ok he can access the record
} else {
    // He can not access the record
}
```

If the user has access to the record, you have to update "lock" so that no other can access it.

```
 if (!$sample->lock || (strtotime($sample->lock) < strtotime('-15minutes'))) {
    // Ok he can access the record
    $sample->lock = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $sample->save();
    // Return view, etc.
 } else ...
```

Now lets look at the "update" method. Once the record is updated, you want to reset "lock", so that the next user can edit the record again. Just add this line and update the record as usual:

```
$sample->lock = null;
```

Now only 1 user can edit a record at a time.

You can also create a "force unlock" method, with which a user can reset "lock" without having to wait 15 minutes.

This is a simple implementation. It works better with javascript because you can check in real time if somebody is editing the record.

Comment: Good effort: but there is a problem if the user just edited the page but did not save the record, now lock key was set but nobody including the same user can edit the record if he has closed the browser.

Comment: Well he has to wait 15 minutes in worst case. If its only small edits you can also set it to 5 minutes.
And i detailed this in my post, please read it :D
And if you want to know more about the forceUnlock don't hesitate to ask

Comment: Along with forceUnlock, tell me why you did not add the field like eiditing_by where we can set the id of the User that is currently editing the record ??

Comment: I didn't need to know who was editing(it was not in the use cases), and the force unlock would solve it for the editor and the users that want to edit.
Another idea: Only allow force unlock after 5 minutes, and disable lock after 15 minutes.

Comment: What you also can do is to use this editing_by field. So now the record will be locked until this exact user saves or cancels the edit. If another user wants to edit the record, the editing user receives a notification in which he can either unlock the record or inform the other user that he is still editing it.
But that would require you have a notification system in place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a column named like `editing` to your tables and corresponding model attribute.

check if`editing` is `false` then let the user to edit.

In any user edit change its value to true,

Comment: what if i click edit button and dont change it for few hours ??? This might create problem so i initially had this thought but it could be tidious in that case .

Answer (score 1):

**concurrent access** issue can be solved in a much easier, yet more efficient way than lock fields:

1. add a `version` field to your table migration with a default value of **0**.

   `$table->smallInteger('version')->default(0);`
2. the `version` value will be incremented on every successful update operation.
3. the update operation will not succeed if the `version` value of the updated record does not equal the version value of the stored record.

**example** - two users trying to update a product record, so they send an ***edit*** request to your application:

1. your application sends an instance of the product to each user, with a `version` value of **0**.
2. the first user finishes updating first, and sends an ***update*** request holding the product fields in the request body including the `version` value of **0** to your application.
3. the application checks if the received `version` value equals the stored value in the db.
4. the values are both **0**, so the first user updates the product successfully, and the application increments the version value, so now it's **1**.
5. the second user finishes updating, and sends an ***update*** request too.
6. the application checks if the received `version` value (**0**), equals the stored value in the db (**1**).
7. the operation fails because the values are not equal, and the second user has to refresh the editing page (send a new ***edit*** request to your application).

**update function:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // request validation here  
    $product = Product::find($id);
    if ($request->version == $product->version) {
        // update here
        $product->version = $product->version + 1;
        $product->save();
        return response()->json("product updated successfully!", 200);
    }
    return response()->json("concurrent access: the product has been updated by another user!", 400);
}
```

this way, the record is always available for updating, but the update operation fails if 2 or more users tried to update the same record at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve done sth similar, but when user sending „put”, first checking if data wasn’t changed by someone else at the same time, if not - update, else back with info and new data.

You can check only „updated-at” date, or check all data.