# Best way to prevent simultaneous model mutations in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

It's probably one of the most common issues with concurrent users working in the same app.

User A fetches a model from the database, which is shown to the user on the screen.  He performs some actions, and updates values of that object.

At a certain time, it saves the model.  Little did user A know that between the time that he fetched the model, and saves the modified model, user B already fetched the same model, and submitted his changes to the database.  Result: the changes of user B are lost.

I've solved this same problem many times already, and usually do it like this:

1/ add an attribute to the model `$version`

2/ upon creating a new model, we set `$version = 1`

3/ when fetching the model, the version attribute is obviously also fetched.

4/ when saving modified model, I only save `... where id = $model->id AND WHERE version = $model->version`  At the same time, I'm updating `$version = $version + 1`

When that update throws a "no records updated" from the database, I search for the model using id only; if I can fetch that, i know that the model existed, but that the version does no longer match.  I then raise an exception to the user (saying 'someone or something already modified the model')

I believe it's the only correct way to make sure that you are always updating the latest version of the object.  You can obviously also use the updated_at attribute to compare that you still have the same version of the object, but theoretically another user may have updated it nevertheless.

Now I'm struggling with how to set this logic up in Laravel.  I want to create a trait that I can use on a model that basically does what I describe above, but I'm struggling with what I should do really.

I know I can override `protected function setKeysForSaveQuery($query)` to have it update `where id = $this->id and version = $this->version` but when I do that, and laravel does not update anything, I'm not getting an exception that allows me to determine that the update failed because the version didn't match...

I want to avoid having to write code where I encapsulate the save in a transaction, and have to validate the versions every time I save a model; looking for a way to *put this in my base models* by including a trait, so that it works *automagically*.

Any input would be much appreciated.

-- added example:

Imagine the following:

```
$modelcopy1 = App\Model::find(1);  // version = 1
$modelcopy2 = App\Model::find(1);  // version = 1

$modelcopy1->save(); // this should update version in database to 2
                     // also $modelcopy1->version should now hold 2

$modelcopy2->save(); // this should now throw an exception
                     // because copy 1 still references version 1
                     // database version is already at 2
```

So basically, I need logic in the `->save()` that validates that the model value for the version attribute matches the current database version, and I need a sync so that when the update is done, the model version attribute is updated to the most recent version.

The save should look like this imo:

```
UPDATE Model
SET version = version + 1, attr1 = :attr1, attr2 = :attr2, ...
WHERE version = $model->version
AND id = $model->id
```

IF UPDATE successful --> make sure that $model->version is updated to new version value

IF UPDATE is unsuccessful THEN SELECT * FROM Model WHERE id = $model->id

IF model found, then THROW ERROR 'model was already updated by someone else' ELSE THROW ERROR 'model does not exist'

I hope this makes sense.  In my opinion such a locking preventing mechanism should be part of any 'adult' framework, but it seems very difficult to tie it into the Laravel framework...

Comment: This might be better for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't have code to review yet - I just don't find a proper place to plug it into in the laravel framework...

Comment: Are you having trouble adding a trait or having the trait do things when it's child models update?

Comment: Adding a trait is not an issue.  The issue is that I don't see where in Laravel's framework the best option is to plug into.  The only thing I see, is writing my own `performUpdate`method and override eloquent's, but that doesn't sound like a long lasting solution as it is very sensitives to future version incompatibility, I believe...

Comment: I'm editing the question to add some example...

Comment: Instead of hijacking the save method itself, would it be possible to save the offending record to a separate `revisions` table on version mismatch, and then allow your admins to restore revisions as needed?

Comment: No - There are plenty of use cases that I can imagine where I just don't want something to happen...  Let's say we have invoice items that we save and at the end of the month, We send an invoice for them.  Th elogic would be to create the invoice object, and then update these items and set invoice_id to the new invoice to create the link.  imagine what would occur if we have two jobs concurrently treat the same customer; it would create two invoice models, and the items might be linked to one, and then updated to be linked to the second.  This is a very common issue that needs decent handling.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to write a trait that will perform the check to see if the model has been updated since the current one was received, and throw back something you can hook onto to notify the user? I would look into making a base model that all of your models extend, and using model events in that base model. You may not even need a trait if you just have all models extend the base model. See below sample model event method:

```
protected static function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    static::saving(function($thisModel){
        $changes = Model::where('version', $thisModel->version)
            ->where('id', $thisModel->id)->first()
        /** if changes->version matches this one, good, if not, set some
         *  property on the model that can be checked.   
         */
    }
}
```

This will happen *as* the model is saving, and if you `return false;` at any point in the method, the save will fail and the model will not be saved.

If you still want to use a trait, be sure that the boot method follows this format: bootTraitName(), or it won't boot on the implementing classes' boot. This is a tricky question with a lot of different angles, but I hope I at least gave you something to consider.

Edit: I've never used model events on a base model, so I'm not sure if the `parent::boot();` is necessary. May have to test.

Comment: You can use `$original = $thisModel->getOriginal();` in your `saving` method to get the value before the changes (which are in `$thisModel`)

Comment: While that is something that would work - this would ONLY work when this is enclosed in a transaction, and the record locked.
This would be my 'second option' and I have that developed already.

It just doesn't cover 'all' scenarios; the best option would still be to have the update statement itself check that the versions match, because now you still have a - albeit small - window between this check and the actual update in which another process can still update the database version.

What @ljubadr suggests is good too, but can become a real issue when you have lengthy process...

Comment: Also, I want to keep performance in mind as well - your suggestion fires an additional query on each save operation...

Comment: and we will use a trait nevertheless; we don't need / want all models to support this, so we are just using the trait for the business critical models...

Comment: and yes - you need the `parent::boot()`- another reason why I prefer a trait - you avoid risking forgetting to add that ;-)

Comment: Hmm, that is true. I did not consider the time window between the call in the boot method and the actual save. Nothing I've ran across could help with making the update itself check, sadly.

Comment: Check [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477857/laravel-stop-concurrent-access-to-record)

Comment: I agree and it’s a real miss if you want to build “(near-) enterprise” applications with laravel...  should be made part of the eloquent framework imo...